# How can I update the Epiphany browser flash player?

Tags: epiphany

I am using loki beta 2 version. but i have problem with epiphany web browser several times, it asking about flash player. How can i update epiphany browser flash player?
I installed adobe flash player but couldn't install it.
If anyone can help me about flash player issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your browsers and remove your flash installation

```
sudo apt purge --remove flashplugin-installer adobe-flashplugin
sudo apt autoremove
```

Now install pepperflash-plugin for Chromium and Firefox (works for all other browsers)

```
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

and it should say that you have Flas version 22 installed.

Comment: Thank you so much, Giovanni Caligaris. Its working nicely.

Comment: this just worked for me !
it is scary doing command line stuff but so simple really.
im on elementary OS 5.0 Juno